# Issues in setting up https for domain. Files are on Amazon Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I want to setup https for my domain name. My files are on AWS Beanstalk(php website)

I have my namecheap ssl for the domain registered. 
On EC2 Console:
The ELB was configured by default. I added my SSL to I AM and attached with the ELB that was created with the project. I want to terminate the HTTPS requests from the web at my ELB and send http requests to my instance.

Security groups:
ELB: the default elb (http, https and ssh ports configured) and default vpc is attached to ELB(http and https configured. source is 0.0.0.0 for all)

Instance: default vpc security group is attached.

When I try to do https://the_aws_elb_link : 
chrome error: NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
safari error: host name mismatch

I checked md5 for all the ssl uploads made. They check out.

When I try to enter my domain name with https: This site can’t be reached

What I want: https://www .mydomain .com and authentication at my ELB

[elb listners configured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8ynx.png)
[CNAME settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i8rg.png)

Comment: What listeners did you set for your ELB? And of course the SSL will not work for https://the_aws_elb_link as you bout the ssl for www.yourdomain.com.

Comment: http 80 http 80
https 443 https 443 ssl certificate i uploaded

Comment: Check below answer you have to setup that way then it will work

Comment: Check edited answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set up the ELB listeners this way then it will work.

[image]

Your Domain is pointing to the EC2 IP address it should point to the AWS ELB C-Name then it will serve the SSL Certificate.

```
ping www.lbacs.org
PING www.lbacs.org (98.124.199.6): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
```

Comment: I used the exact setup you said.
When I try to connect using https://www.mydomain .com : It says site cant be reached

Comment: Let me know what you get after above setup

Comment: Its is strange. Gives me this error:
Removed listener on port: 80.
Failed to create listener on port: 80. Listeners can't talk to InstancePort 80 with secure and insecure protocols at the same time

Comment: I am guessing it has something to do with the security groups I have setup?
I have also done this when I was trying everything I could: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html

Comment: Add rule to your security group https 443 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: That rule is already present in both the security groups attached to my ELB.
BTW I was able to change my ELB listners to match the screenshot you have uploaded.

Comment: What is your domain?

Comment: [link]www.lbacs.org this is

Comment: On chrome: it will say: This page is insecure (broken HTTPS). on going to my domain name

Comment: Dude your domain ping www.lbacs.org is pointing to the Server IP address it should point to the C-Name of the ELB then it will server the SSL certificate

Comment: Do the DNS change it will take approx 12 hrs for propagation then check if the https is working

Comment: I am not able to set a CNAME for my elb. It says that the ELB link is not a registered domain.
So i have already setup a URL Frame to my ELB A name.
What I suspect is that the security groups configured are not allowing free communications between the ELB and the Instance.

I can relate to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915431/cant-access-https-site-on-elastic-beanstalk-after-configuring-https-in-the-load?rq=1

Comment: You don't have to set up a CNAME for your ELB you have to change the DNS for your domain "www.lbacs.org" and add a C-name pointing to the ELB link some thing like this "your-elb.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com" so then the domain will run through the ELB and server the SSL certificate. There is no issue in security groups. Never use ELB A-Name as that IP address is static and changes frequently always point to the loadbalancer endpoint using the C-name

Comment: I have added a screenshot of my DNS settings.
Can you check and tell if it is correct?

Comment: No your DNS is wrong URL frame will not work as your SSL certificate is for the domain you have to remove that URL frame and add the Load balancer "your-elb.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com" in C-Name.

Comment: Got it working! Thanks man. I was making a very stupid mistake.