# This site can’t be reached ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT Elastic Beanstalk HTTPS

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a laravel application that I am trying to configure use HTTPS. With HTTP the app works fine. I've created a SSL certificate, authenticated it using DNS, and then added it to my route 53 set. I then used these steps:

[Certificate config steps:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html)

> 1. Open the Elastic Beanstalk console.
> 2. Navigate to the management page for your environment.
> 3. Choose Configuration.
> 4. On the Load balancer configuration card, choose Modify.
>
>    Note
>
>    If the Load balancer configuration card doesn't have a Modify button,
>      your environment doesn't have a load balancer.
> 5. On the Modify load balancer page, the procedure varies depending on
>      the type of load balancer associated with your environment.
>
>    Classic Load Balancer
>
>    - Choose Add listener.
>    - In the Classic Load Balancer listener dialog box, configure the
>        following settings:
>
>      - For Listener port, type the incoming traffic port, typically 443.
>      - For Listener protocol, choose HTTPS.
>      - For Instance port, type 80.
>      - For Instance protocol, choose HTTP.
>      - For SSL certificate, choose your certificate.
>    - Choose Add.

I'm still getting:

> This site can’t be reached www.myexample.ca took too long to respond.
>   Search Google for example.ca log
>   ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

**Edit**

`curl -v mysite.ca`

```
* Rebuilt URL to: mysite.ca/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80 failed: Operation timed out
* Failed to connect to mysite.ca port 80: Operation timed out
* Closing connection 0
```

Note: I replaced the IP of my site with the local ip for privacy reasons.

**Edit 2 Route 53**

## Record 1

**Name**

mysite.ca

**Type**

A

**Value**

[Sites IP]

**TTL**

300

## Record 2

**Name**

mysite.ca

**Type**

NS

**Value**

ns-1053.awsdns-03.org.

ns-578.awsdns-08.net.

ns-1860.awsdns-40.co.uk.

ns-274.awsdns-34.com.

**TTL**

172800

## Record 3

**Name**

mysite.ca

**Type**

SOA

**Value**

ns-578.awsdns-08.net. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com.

**TTL**

900

## Record 4

**Name**

mysslhash.mysite.ca

**Type**

CNAME

**Value**

A hash

**TTL**

300

## Record 5

**Name**

www.mysite.ca

**Type**

A

**Value**

ALIAS mysite.ca

**TTL**

**Edit 3**

I'm also using hover for my sites name

Comment: Can you do a curl with -v option to see what exactly is failing, is it the connection or the handshake?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. In my terminal just `curl -v option myexamplesite.com` ?

Comment: just do curl -v https://yoursite

Comment: @JunedAhsan just edited the question for you

Comment: You are running this on the ec2 instance or from your local machine? Why it is resolving to the localhost address 127.0.0.1? What is you route53 conifg?

Comment: No no no, that's not the actual IP. I'm just putting 127.0.0.1 for privacy reasons, if that makes sense. I can edit my question to include my route 53 if you'd like?

Comment: @JunedAhsan just edited comment to include route53. Sorry for the bad format

Comment: @JunedAhsan, is it possible that ec2>security groups could be playing into this? 

I found both of these links, but they're old and don't really seem to explain what to configure properly:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=120076


And

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915431/cant-access-https-site-on-elastic-beanstalk-after-configuring-https-in-the-load